# How to stop CORS error when sending headers?

Tags: .htaccess, header, cors

I want to be connected to a remote API through AJAX via http://localhost:5500. This is my code with a sample URL:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.website.com/",
    headers: { 'x-api-key': 'Sd6g8uieEk8couufkxv9MVp5xdDJBcTSA' },
    type: "GET",
    withCredentials: false,
    success: function(data) { console.log(data) }
});
```

If I remove the `x-api-key` part from this code, I have not any issue and receive responses. But, as I add this section to the code, I receive CORS errors:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://api.website.com/' from origin
> 'http://localhost:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
> HTTP ok status.

I have added different settings in the .htaccess file, but they could not solve the issue:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:5500"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
```

I have read many articles, and did many changes on settings, but I could not solve the issue. May you help me please?

Comment: As you config stands now, you'd have issues if your request were credentialed, but that's not the case here. I'm not entirely sure why you're getting an error. However, try this one thing: rather than using the wildcard (`*`), try explicitly listing `x-api-key` in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

Comment: I've changed the code with `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, x-api-key, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"`. Also, I removed `credential` line from the code, but the problem still exists.